# Laravel - Getting first thread per forum all() result

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I'm learning VueJS and trying to develop a forum system 
I am trying to get the latest post from the threads relationship per forum in my forum model.

This is my Forum Model

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Forum extends Model
{
    public $table = 'forums';
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function threads() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Thread')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    }

    public function getFirstThread() {
        return $this->threads()->first();
    }
}
```

So I thought maybe this would work but it didn't

```
Forum::with('getFirstThread')->get();
```

Any idea's how I can achieve this without having to loop through everything and getting first thread for every result?

**TLDR:** Trying to get the latest Thread per Forum without having to loop through all forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `$append` the method results by using `getMethodNameAttribute()`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Forum extends Model
{
    public $table = 'forums';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $appends = ['firstthread'];   

    public function threads() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Thread')->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    }

    public function getFirstThreadAttribute() {
        return $this->threads()->first();
    }
}
```

Comment: awesome! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0):

You could define another mapping as `hasOne` in your model to get latest thread per forum, Call `latest('id')` on your mapping and pass `id` as a column to sort

```
public function latest_threads() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\Thread')->latest('id');
}
```

Then you can easily eager load your relationship as

```
Forum::with('latest_threads')->get();
```